# Knapsack problem, partition problem, or in general dynamic algorithm with negative numbers allowed

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

How to think about dynamic algorithms which allows negative integers in input (where it's problematic, because obviously it's not always the case)?

Examples:

- [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with negative numbers in set allowed
- [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with negative weights are allowed

Is there some general idea to handle these or other similar dynamic algorithms?

Comment: What angle are you coming from? Some problems change in complexity when negative numbers pop up (e.g. SSSPP), some don't (e.g. sorting). Dynamic programming does not have, in principle, a problem with negative numbers; in fact, there may not be any numbers at all. So, what is your question, really?

Comment: I know, that negative numbers (if they are) are not always problematic. I am just saying that there are some problems with numbers (knapsack problem, partition problem) which are using only non-negative numbers in their dynamic algorithms.
Notice, that negative numbers are not allowed in these problems for similar reason.
My question, in general, is - Are there dynamic algorithms for above (stated in question) problems with negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the two examples you mention, the dynamic programming algorithms work just as well. Let's take *partition* as an example. The dynamic programming approach computes, for every $m$, the sums of all subsets of $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$. This works just as well if negative numbers are allowed. The range of the table has to be modified accordingly, to account fo the largest possible positive and negative amounts. With knapsack it's similar, and I'll let you work out the details.